# Ubuntu 20.04 tries and fails to start mysql server on any apt operation

Tags: apt, 20.04, mysql

I recently needed to install MariaDB and installed it. I had several issues with starting it and decided to remove the package. After that, I was unable to start my MySQL server either. I can't remember for the life of me what the problems were. I'm not even sure I knew at any point but finally, I decided to reinstall the MySQL server altogether.

The current situation is that I cant run apt without getting an error that says MySQL Comunity Server cant be started.

Here is the output of `sudo apt install rar`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rar is already the newest version (2:5.5.0-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.22-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-12-09 14:48:36 +03; 14ms ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 19528 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 19593 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 19593 (code=exited, status=3)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.22-1ubuntu20.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't understand what makes apt rely on starting a MySQL server. I don't know how to make it not do so. I know this may not be a sufficient amount of information but it's all I have.

Comment: You have never properly installed `mysql`. Now `apt` notices this and tries to finish the job. Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and see if you can get it to work. After that, `apt` will run smoothly again.

Comment: No luck. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` just ran without any output. I did `sudo dpkg --configure mysql-community-server`, It tried to start mysql again.